# Qt creator странно себя ведет

Tags: qt, c++

Подскажите пожалуйста, что делать с qt, запуская даже такую прогу:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    cout << "hello world";
    return 0;
}
```

Выдает в консоли:

> `19:25:02: Выполняется сборка проекта project...`
>
> `19:25:02: Запускается: «c:\qtsdk\desktop\qt\4.8.0\msvc2010\bin\qmake.exe» C:\Users\саня\Desktop\project\project.pro -r -spec win32-msvc2010 "CONFIG+=declarative_debug`
>
> `Cannot find file: c:\Users\саня\Desktop\project\project.pro.`
>
> `19:25:02: Процесс «c:\qtsdk\desktop\qt\4.8.0\msvc2010\bin\qmake.exe» завершился с кодом 2.`
>
> `Возникла ошибка при сборке проекта project (цель: Desktop)`
>
> `Во время выполнения сборки на этапе «qmake»`

PS находил в инете топик с подобной проблемой. Там посоветовали убрать галку с пункта "Использовать теневую сборку", но это не помогло..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А если попробовать запустить из папки без кириллицы в пути? Раньше у него с этим вроде проблемы были. Слеши, я так понимаю, сьелись парсером на сайте?

Comment: ДА!! Спасибо, вы были правы.. Запустил в каталоге без кирилицы и все ок!